# Question on Tensor Contraction Statement

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

I am reading the following statement that says:

> From tensor contraction we can write
>
> $R_{kl} =  \sum_i \sum_m g^{im}R_{iklm}$

Can any one explain how that statement is derived? R is a Riemann Tensor. Please note there is no context to the above statement. Its the first step in a series of steps that proves a statement.

Comment: Your source contracted the Riemann tensor's first and fourth indices? Every source I've seen has gone with first and third or second and fourth, so yours introduces a sign change.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to understand this contraction or you know it but you want to know why it gives $R_{kl}$.

Comment: @Semsem I would like to understand this "contraction" and know why it gives $R_{kl}$